# Why ThickBox gallery doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, gallery, thickbox

There is a screenshot page created using 'thickbox 3.1' jquery plugin  (http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/). On the page I was able to create a 'single image' using the following template:

```
<a href="/picts/screen/report_online2.png" class="thickbox" title="title1">
    <img src="/picts/screen/report_online2_.png" alt="title1">
</a>
```

But attempt to create gallery images using the following template:

```
<a href="/picts/screen/report_online2.png" class="thickbox" title="title1" rel="gallery-plants">
    <img src="/picts/screen/report_online2_.png" alt="title1">
</a>
```

failed: instead of displaying dialog (window) with images the only "progress" bar is displayed...

The only difference in the source code I see is an additional attribute (rel="gallery-plants").

Please advise, why it could not work in my case?

Any feedback is welcome!

Thank you very much!

P.S. Tried in Google Chrome and Mozilla

P.P.S. If the source code of implementation could be helpful please use the following page: http://vfm-elita.com/screenshots

EDIT: problem description was added.

Comment: Why downvote? I don't really understand what's wrong, don't see any JavaScript errors... Have no any idea how to investigate... Hope to find understanding...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't resolve an issue, as an alternative approach, I've tried lightbox2 - it's 'example' works locally in html file, but not in asp.net web site... spend few hours to find a differences...

and switched after that to lightbox from jQuery (http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/), work fine for me now.